# Module parse failed: unexpected token, you may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to create a npm package out of create-react-app typescript template. so far, the build is being generated but while testing it locally via `npm install github_username/repo_name#branch_name` it installs the package in other testing project, but I am getting this error while trying to run it.

These are the steps

**Step 1** created a new react project using `npx create-react-app project_name --template typescript`

**Step 2** Isolated components that I wanted to publish as npm package by creating `lib/components` inside `src` and `lib/index.ts` for exporting them.

**Step 3** Installed Babel and build the `dist` in the `root` with some babel configuration.
`{ "presets": [ [ "@babel/env", { "targets": { "edge": "17", "firefox": "60", "chrome": "67", "safari": "11.1" }, "useBuiltIns": "usage", "corejs": "3.6.5" } ], "@babel/preset-react" ] }`

**Step 4** In `package.json`, under scripts, replace the build script with the following:

`"build": "rm -rf dist && NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files"`

**Step 6** `npm run build`

**Step 7** Pushed to GitHub and install from github repo into diffrent react project and then the error came.

[image]

I am not really sure what exactly causing this error, but upon checking it seems like babel or webpack error, I tried changing some values inside `tsconfig.json` and `webpack.config.ts` (in the package repo) but it didn't solve it, also I am not very familiar with webpack.